# table filtering by 5 separate input blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, html-table

I've been trying to write a function in javascript so I can filter a table by 5 separate input boxes, one for each parameter of the table. W3schools had a solution, but it just covered one column; I found a bunch of other answers here on "how to filter a table by multiple input boxes", but they either didn't work or the other box would've overwritten the filtering process, for example, if I'd written "x" in box one and "y" in box two, the table would've to consist every "y" included `td` in the column even the ones without "x". Any solution to that? (nothing to add to the sixth column, that meant to stay like this)

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="inid" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="ID">
<input type="text" id="inplat" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Platform">
<input type="text" id="inloc" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Location">
<input type="text" id="incount" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="T-Count">
<input type="text" id="inauthor" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Author">

<div id="table_div">
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr class="header">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>T-Count</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2-12-8374857-232</td>
                <td>PC</td>
                <td>Chongqing</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Urben</td>
                <td>More Info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3-23-3939473-324</td>
                <td>PS</td>
                <td>Dubai</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Hichkas</td>
                <td>More Info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3-43-3245235-432</td>
                <td>Xbox</td>
                <td>Paris</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>TheChicken</td>
                <td>More Info</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1-24-2594549-124</td>
                <td>Stadia</td>
                <td>Berlin</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Scat1620</td>
                <td>More Info</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you in control of the HTML code yourself? Or does it come from an external source you have not control over?

Comment: Written by me... @yunzen

Comment: Then I'd recommend to change the table code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my proposal for you

It uses some enhanced JS tricks

```js
// do everything inside a block to not conflict with global namespace
{
  "use strict";
  
  // define some magic values
  const formSelector = '[data-filter-table-target]'
  const columnSelector = '[data-column]'
  const rowSelector = ':scope > tbody > tr';
  const filteredClassName = 'filtered';
  
  // define small Helper function that do exactly one thing
  
  // returns an HTML element that matches the selector from the data-filter-table-target argument
  const getTarget = form => document.querySelector(form.dataset.filterTableTarget)
  // get all the first class rows (i.e. not nested inside a table) from this table's body
  const getRows = table => Array.from(table.querySelectorAll(rowSelector))
  // get the values from this form's inputs, which have a data-column argument
  const getFilterValues = form =>  Array.from(form.querySelectorAll(columnSelector)).map(inp => ({'column': inp.dataset.column, 'value': inp.value}));

  // check, if this cells text contains the value
  const checkCellValue = (cell, value) => (new RegExp(value, 'i')).test(cell.textContent)
  
  // get a table row's cell which data-column argument value matches the value argument
  const getCell = (row, value) => row.querySelector(`[data-column="${value.column}"`)
  
  // filter a row, if it does not match the value
  const filterRow = (row, values) => {
    const filtered = values.reduce((carry, value) => {
      if (! checkCellValue(getCell(row, value), value.value)) { return true;}
      return carry
    }, false)
    
    if (filtered) {
      row.classList.add(filteredClassName)
    } else {
      row.classList.remove(filteredClassName)
    }
  }
  
  // check all rows, if they should be filtered
  const filterRows = (rows, values) => {
    rows.forEach(row => filterRow(row, values))
  }
  
  // bahaviour on input
  const onInput = e => {
    // check, if input is called from inside a form which serves as filter
    const form = e.target.closest(formSelector)
    // otherwise return
    if (!form) {return;}
    
    const target = getTarget(form)
    const rows = getRows(target)
    const values = getFilterValues(form)
    
    filterRows(rows, values)
    
  }
  
  // check for the global input event
  document.addEventListener('input', onInput)
}
```

```css
.filtered {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- the data-filter-table-target argument points to the table to be filtered -->
<form data-filter-table-target="#myTable">
  <!-- the data-column arguments point to the table cells with the same argument -->
  <input type="text" id="inid"     placeholder="ID"       data-column="ID">
  <input type="text" id="inplat"   placeholder="Platform" data-column="Platform">
  <input type="text" id="inloc"    placeholder="Location" data-column="Location">
  <input type="text" id="incount"  placeholder="T-Count"  data-column="TCount">
  <input type="text" id="inauthor" placeholder="Author"   data-column="Author">
</form>
<div id="table_div">
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>T-Count</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-column="ID">2-12-8374857-232</td>
        <td data-column="Platform">PC</td>
        <td data-column="Location">Chongqing</td>
        <td data-column="TCount">4</td>
        <td data-column="Author">Urben</td>
        <td>More Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-column="ID">3-23-3939473-324</td>
        <td data-column="Platform">PS</td>
        <td data-column="Location">Dubai</td>
        <td data-column="TCount">3</td>
        <td data-column="Author">Hichkas</td>
        <td>More Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-column="ID">3-43-3245235-432</td>
        <td data-column="Platform">Xbox</td>
        <td data-column="Location">Paris</td>
        <td data-column="TCount">2</td>
        <td data-column="Author">TheChicken</td>
        <td>More Info</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-column="ID">1-24-2594549-124</td>
        <td data-column="Platform">Stadia</td>
        <td data-column="Location">Berlin</td>
        <td data-column="TCount">5</td>
        <td data-column="Author">Scat1620</td>
        <td>More Info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. It's working fine, but when I added a button to reset them (do ```value=""``` although it clears the inputs the table remains filtered. Any solution to that?